# How to Free RAM at Silverlight/WPF?

Tags: wpf, silverlight

How to Free RAM at Silverlight/WPF ?  I define a UserControl MyUC that has a Image and three Textblock.   I add 10000 MyUCs to a Grid, then clear the Grid's Children,but RAM is not Freed! Why?
MyUC:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="32"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding ICO}" Width="32" Height="32"/>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" Width="359" Margin="0,0,-189,0">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding URL}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Code:

```
MyUC uc = null;
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
  uc = new MyUC();
  this.LayoutRoot.Children.Clear();
  this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(uc);
}
```

Help me? 3KS!

Comment: I am a beginner. Can you help me? Which book?

Comment: How do you know the memory has not been freed? Is there a problem?

Comment: IE has seized memory 50M when the UI loaded.Then i do the code(for ...10000),IE eat memory 60M,and more...more.... Why?

Comment: Why not? If you PC has the memory available and no process needs it, why spend time cleaning it up? That is the way the .NET Garbage Collector works; only when needed.

Comment: you could call GC.Collect(); but note this, if you call this method, then you are doing something wrong in the first place. have a read of this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2004/11/29/271829.aspx

Comment: Do NOT call GC.Collect(); it will make your app even slower.

Comment: Any good way to control/resolve it in SL/WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is you don't do anything explicit to release memory in the case you have provided.

As each instance of your MyUC class goes out of scope, the Garbage Collector will determine that it is no longer reachable.  At the next garbage collection, the unreachable instances will be 'marked' and the memory will be compacted.  It's all fundamental to how .NET works.

Whether or not your diagnostic for measuring memory is detecting the effects of garbage collection is another story, and you didn't provide any info on what diagnostics you are using.

**Garbage collection in the Microsoft .NET common language runtime environment completely absolves the developer from tracking memory usage and knowing when to free memory. However, you'll want to understand how it works. Part 1 of this two-part article on .NET garbage collection**

Source:  Jeffery Richter  [Garbage Collection: Automatic Memory Management in the Microsoft .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx)

Comment: My call Fun: [MyUC uc = null; private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) { uc = new MyUC(); this.LayoutRoot.Children.Clear(); this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(uc); } } ] IE Can eat 500M memory if you click the Button3 more than once. Why?

Comment: As pointed out above, you don't.  C# is a garbage collected language. By the way, I have assumed that your MyUC class does not have any aberrant weirdness in it that prevents it's destruction in the 1st generation.

Comment: MyUC: Code:[public partial class MyUC : UserControl
    {
        public MyUC()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }] , MyUC do nothing....

Comment: MyUC XAML:[<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="32"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding ICO}" Width="32" Height="32"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" Width="359" Margin="0,0,-189,0">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding URL}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>]

Comment: Thanks! WinForm is not Problem,but SL/WPF has happen! I want to know how to resolve it at SL/WPF? I will read Jeffrey's article . 3KS!